# heroku identifies a ruby version different from the one I have

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Every time I try to run "heroku run rails db:migrate" I get this error "Your Ruby version is 2.7.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.6".  I've changed the ruby version in the Gemfile from 2.6.6 to 2.7.0 and When I run bundle install I get the error "Your Ruby version is 2.6.6, but your Gemfile specified 2.7.0"

Checking my ruby version "ruby --version" I get ruby 2.6.6p146 (2020-03-31 revision 67876)

How can I either have Heroku recognize the 2.6.6 version or update it to 2.7.0 ?

Thank you

Comment: i believe removing ruby version from gemfile/lock and putting it in `.ruby-version` will resolve issue (i'm running a ruby 2.3.1/ rails 4.2 app on heroku with such configuration)

Comment: Is your question "How can I use ruby 2.6 on heroku", or is it "How can I install ruby 2.7 locally"? The issue at the moment appears to be your local environment does not match heroku, and so specifying a version in the `Gemfile` will be inconsistent for one or the other.

Comment: Only specifying the version in `.ruby-version` (or not specifying it at all!!) may resolve the error, however, it doesn't fix the fact that your local machine and heroku are running different software versions - so you **may** encounter issues if the two versions behave differently.

Comment: @TomLord if there's a way to make sure heroku uses 2.6, that would be great.

Comment: You need to update your local Ruby to to 2.7.0.  You are saying in your Gemfile to use 2.7.0, bundle install is failing because it isn't available.

Answer (score -2):

Try run:

`heroku run rails db:drop`
`heroku run rails db:create`
`heroku run rails db:migrate`